# Passing state between functional steps in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

Is there a better way to pass state between steps.

For example every time a card is taken form the deck we have to create a new Deck and return it so that the next step can use it etc

Is there a better way to do this using Cats for example?

```
trait BlackjackSteps {
    def gamerTakesTwoCards(deck: Deck): (Gamer, Deck)
    def dealerTakesTwoCards(deck: Deck): (Dealer, Deck)
    def isBlackjack(gamer: Gamer, dealer: Dealer): Option[Player]
    def gamerToDrawCards(gamer: Gamer, deck: Deck): Gamer
    def dealerToDrawCards(dealer: Dealer, deck: Deck, gamer: Gamer): Dealer
    def determineWinner(gamer: Gamer, dealer: Dealer): Player
  }
```

The Game:

- a gamer and dealer play
- they both draw two cards
- if no 21 winner
- players keep drawing cards until 17
- highest player not over 21 points wins

EDIT -----

Thanks for the responses. I just want to see what people think of this approach?

How about this?

```
trait CardPicker {
    def pick(numberCards:Int): List[Card]
  }

  abstract class BlackjackSteps(cardPicker: CardPicker) {
    def gamerTakesTwoCards(gamer: Gamer): Gamer = {
      gamer.copy(cards = cardPicker.pick(2))
    }
    def dealerTakesTwoCards(dealer: Dealer): Dealer = {
      dealer.copy(cards = cardPicker.pick(2))
    }
    def isBlackjack(gamer: Gamer, dealer: Dealer): Option[Player] = {
     if(gamer.isBlackjack) Some(gamer)
     else if(dealer.isBlackjack) Some(dealer)
     else None
    }
    def gamerToDrawCards(gamer: Gamer): Gamer = {
      def drawCards(gamerPickingCards: Gamer): Gamer = gamer match {
        case _ if(gamerPickingCards.points < drawThreshold) =>
          drawCards(Gamer(gamerPickingCards.name, gamerPickingCards.cards ++ cardPicker.pick(1)))
        case _ => gamerPickingCards
      }
      drawCards(gamer)
    }
    def dealerToDrawCards(dealer: Dealer, gamer: Gamer): Dealer = {
      def drawCards(dealerPickingCards: Dealer): Dealer = dealer match {
        case _ if(dealerPickingCards.points < gamer.points) =>
          drawCards(Dealer(dealerPickingCards.name, dealerPickingCards.cards ++ cardPicker.pick(1)))
        case _ => dealerPickingCards
      }
      drawCards(dealer)
    }
    def determineWinner(gamer: Gamer, dealer: Dealer): Player = {
      if(gamer.points == dealer.points || gamer.points > dealer.points) gamer
      else dealer
    }
  }
```

Here CardPicker has side effects that we can delay until the end of the world.

Is this too crazy?

Comment: I like this question because it helps raise a though experiment for me: what situations does functional programming actually hinder software development? And I can see game development being an area where functional programming is difficult to adhere to strictly.

Comment: @Ellesedil: There's a Mario Bros. clone in Haskell that was written as part of a thesis, and I also remember seeing a blog series on Purely Functional Retrogames. I think there is a Space Invader clone in Idris (which was jokingly used to prove that Idris is Tetris-complete, since Tetris obviously reduces to Space Invaders). For example, you can model an event loop as co-recursion over co-data, or using Functional Reactive Programming. You can model global game state using the State Monad (or maybe figure out a design that doesn't need global game state).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a great usecase for the `State` monad. Here's something that could get you started:

```
trait BlackjackSteps {
  def gamerTakesTwoCards: State[Deck, Gamer]
  def dealerTakesTwoCards: State[Deck, Dealer]
  def isBlackjack(gamer: Gamer, dealer: Dealer): State[Deck, Option[Player]]
  def gamerToDrawCards(gamer: Gamer): State[Deck, Gamer]
  def dealerToDrawCards(dealer: Dealer, gamer: Gamer): State[Deck, Dealer]
  def determineWinner(gamer: Gamer, dealer: Dealer): State[Deck, Player]
}

def gamerTakesTwoCards: State[Deck, Gamer] = 
  State { oldDeck => 
    val gamer = f(oldDeck)
    val newDeck = g(oldDeck)
    (newDeck, gamer)
  }
```

You can check out the official Cats documentation to find out more:
https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/state.html

Comment: where do the functions f and g come form?

Comment: Well, you'll have to fill in the blanks there :)
`State` just wraps a function from an old state to a new state along with a result.

Comment: thanks, also the function signature returns : State[Deck, Gamer] but a tuple is returned (newDeck, gamer) from the implementation, is that correct?

Comment: Not quite, we do return a `State[Deck, Gamer] `, the `State.apply` constructor just uses a function from the oldDeck to a tuple of the new state and the result. :)

Comment: I edited the code a bit, maybe it makes it more clear now?